# foo in any([class.method(), foo.bar(), etc.etc()]) argument of type bool not iterable

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm currently doing a problem set for the 6.00x course, and have run into a strange error.

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ps6_test.py", line 157, in test7PhraseTrigger
    self.assertTrue(pt.evaluate(a), "PhraseTrigger doesn't find phrase in title")
  File "/home/tayler/Dropbox/Programming/6.00x/ProblemSets/ProblemSet6/ps6.py", line 148, in evaluate
    story.getTitle()])
TypeError: argument of type 'bool' is not iterable
```

The segment of code throwing the error is:

```
class PhraseTrigger(Trigger):
    def __init__(self, phrase):
        self.phrase = phrase
    def evaluate(self, story):
        return self.phrase in any([story.getSubject(), story.getSummary(),
            story.getTitle()])
```

I'm running a simple test suite that's provided, that sets up the variables and creates some instances. I'm not sure why the `in any()` is iterating over a boolean after two are compared. Why is `any()` iterating over a boolean after two comparisons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`any` isn't iterating over a boolean, `any` returns a boolean over which `in` tries to iterate. You meant probably this:

```
any(self.phrase in text for text in [
       story.getSubject(), story.getSummary(), story.getTitle()
  ])
```

`any` returns `True` if any of elements of the iterable it is given evaluates to `True` and `False` otherwise.

Simply put, the above code means

*Return True if `any` of these is True: `self.phrase in story.getSubject()`, `self.phrase in story.getSummary()` or `self.phrase in story.getTitle()`*

You can write it in another way:

```
any([self.phrase in story.getSubject(),
     self.phrase in story.getSummary(),
     self.phrase in story.getTitle()
  ])
```

Comment: Hmm... I read the (short) pydoc, and it does appear I'm using `any` wrong. However, the return value isn't correct. It's returning False when it should be returning True...

Comment: Do you use my updated code? I misunderstood your intentions at first.

Comment: Yeah, I updated it. I got it, I just didn't update it correctly. I used `return any(self.phrase for s in [list of stuff])` rather than `return any(self.phrase` **`in s`** `for s in [list of stuff])`

Answer (score 1):

As the error states, `any` returns a boolean. It returns True if any of its arguments return True.

If you want to check if the phrase is any of the values, you probably want:

```
return any([self.phrase in val for val in [story.getSubject(), story.getSummary(), story.getTitle()]])
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks. That what I ended up using after I remembered what `any` was actually doing.

Answer (score 0):

`any()` isn't *iterating* over a boolean, it returns a boolean. It's supposed to do so, see the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any).

So what you're doing is checking whether *any* of the methods `getSubject`,  `getSummary` or `getTitle` returns a value, and then you try to iterate over that True or False value.